# Removing and Reading Characters From a String

Tags: python

So I have a dataframe column `df_Fin['Rate']` of dtype `object`:

1. 0.02
2. 0.15
3. 0.80-
4. 0.10-
5. 0.50

where the hyphens indicate negative numbers.

So I did:

```
df_Fin['Rate2'] = df_Fin['Rate'].replace('-','', regex = True)
df_Fin['Rate2'] = df_Fin['Rate2'].astype(float)
```

This removes the hyphen and lets me do math on it, but I need to know which rows had negative numbers.
But when I do:

```
df_Fin['Negative Rates'] = np.where(df_Fin['Rate'].str.contains('-'), -1, 1)
```

I get all `-1s` in `df_Fin['Negative Rates']`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.endswith`

**Ex:**

```
df_Fin['Negative Rates'] = np.where(df_Fin['Rate'].str.endswith('-'), -1, 1)
```

Demo:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Rate': ['0.02', '0.15', '0.80-', '0.10-', '0.50']})
df['Negative Rates'] = np.where(df['Rate'].str.endswith('-'), -1, 1)
df['Rate2'] = df['Rate'].replace('-','', regex = True)

print(df)

    Rate  Negative Rates Rate2
0   0.02               1  0.02
1   0.15               1  0.15
2  0.80-              -1  0.80
3  0.10-              -1  0.10
4   0.50               1  0.50
```

Comment: @ Rakesh Thanks a lot.  This worked with the following modifications:  `df_Fin['Negative Rates'] = np.where(df_Fin['Rate'].str.endswith('-$'),1,-1)
df_Fin['Rate2'] = df_Fin['Rate'].replace('-','',regex = True).astype(float)`.  I had to add the $ after the hyphen, and also even though this doesn't make intuitive sense, I get the proper result when the -1 is the second value in the np.where statement.  Wierd.